# driver.getCurrentUrl() returns data:, instead of actual URL

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

I'm writing a test with Serenity BDD-Cucumber.

I want to check if the URL is correct when it's navigated. But the result always shows data, and my test fails with driver.getCurrentUrl().

Please see my code below:

### Feature steps:

```
 public void homePageOpens() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("STORE"));
        String homepageUrl = navigationUser.getUrl();
        System.out.println(homepageUrl);
        Assert.assertTrue(homepageUrl.contains("https://www.example.com/index.html"));
        driver.close();
    }
```

---

### Navigation steps:

```
@Step("Get the URL")
public String getUrl() { return basePage.getUrl();
}
```

---

### BasePage:

```
  public String getUrl() {
        System.out.println("just testing");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

---

This also opens a page with URL: "data:," which doesn't close after the test

Answer (score 1):

Use `driver.get` in order to navigate somewhere.

```
String someUrl = "https://www.example.com/index.html";
driver.get(someUrl);
```

This code:

```
public String getUrl() {
        System.out.println("just testing");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

just launch the browser, and the initial url is `data:,`.

Also it's unclear why `BasePage getUrl()` method launches the new webdriver and uses it as a local variable. But in `homePageOpens()` method in feature steps looks like some another driver used..